# Static IP for Parse Server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server

I have some Parse Server installations running on Heroku, and I need to get them static IP addresses.  I've looked into the various add-ons such as Fixie and QuotaGuard Static.  Their documentation indicates that the connection code needs to be changed to use the proxy to get a static IP.  I would really like to avoid editing the Parse Server code, because that will make it much harder to update when a new release of Parse Server comes out.  Is there any way to get a static IP that's transparent to the code running in the dyno?

Should this be on serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get a static IP without using a proxy (and changing code).

From Heroku:

> "The IPs in use by Heroku at any given time are highly dynamic."

See:
https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku